# Porque está dando erro no montador Assembly?

Tags: assembly

Estou tentando aprender Assembly. Ao compilar o seguinte código no FASM ele dá o erro *ilegal instruction* abaixo *section .data*.

Ao remover esse trecho e tentar montar novamente, da o mesmo erro, só que agora no *section .text* e depois no *global _start*.

Depois de tirar tudo ele monta, mas só gera um arquivo *.bin* sem um executável.

```
section .data
    msg     db      'Olá Mundo', 0AH
    len     equ     $-msg

    section .text
    global  _start
    _start: mov     edx, len
            mov     ecx, msg
            mov     ebx, 1
            mov     eax, 4
            int     80h

            mov     ebx, 0
            mov     eax, 1
            int     80h
```

Não estou conseguindo avançar, pois já usei o NASM e também tive dificuldades. Minha máquina é 64 bits, mas, se uma máquina x64 consegue rodar programas x86, isso não devia ser problema.

Mesmo usando o MASM no Windows XP 32 bits ainda não aceitou os programas que tentei compilar (A maioria programas prontos).

Me parece que cada compilador trabalha com regras específicas. Alguém pode me explicar como devo proceder ?

Comment: Tecnicamente não se diz compilador e sim montador. É uma gafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu código há alguns erros:

1. Não foi definido o [formato do executável](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4), se é um programa *console*, use `format PE console` (para **x64**, use `PE64` ao invés de `PE`).
2. Não foi definido o ponto de [entrada do programa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point), para definir utilize a diretiva `entry`.
3. Na definição das seções, há erros de sintaxe, para especificar uma seção você deve colocá-las dentro de aspas `'`.

O código com estas modificações deverá ficar assim:

```
format PE64 console
entry inicio

section '.data'
    msg     db      'Olá Mundo', 0AH
    len     equ     $-msg

    section '.text'
    inicio: mov     edx, len
            mov     ecx, msg
            mov     ebx, 1
            mov     eax, 4
            int     80h

            mov     ebx, 0
            mov     eax, 1
            int     80h
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.